# Javascript create array using foreach checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, checkbox

Ok guys i have this form

```
<input id="valor" name="valor[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input id="valor" name="valor[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input id="valor" name="valor[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input id="valor" name="valor[]" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input id="valor" name="valor[]" type="checkbox" value="5" />
<input id="valor" name="valor[]" type="checkbox" value="6" />

<input id="result" name="result" type="text" />
```

what i need is:

When i check any of the checkboxes an array with the format (for example)

1|2|4

is updated in real time inside the result text field, so i can use in php to explode
i tryed a lot of thins none works

PS. just passing trough post will not be enough i know if i just post this field i gonna have an array but i need to pass to the result field

thanks in advance

Comment: if you explode in php you will also get an array, just like in post... maybe you just need to use your post array correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily execute a [`serialize()` function](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on a form that wraps these checkboxes. The resulting string can be "decoded" in php using the [`parse_str()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

A serialized string of all checkboxes being selected would look like this:

```
valor%5B%5D=1&valor%5B%5D=2&valor%5B%5D=3&valor%5B%5D=4&valor%5B%5D=5&valor%5B%5D=6
```

Passing that value though `parse_str()` will give you something similar to this:

```
[valor] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 6
    )
```

Comment: do u mind show me a example of that?

Comment: There isn't much to be shown... once your users have made their selection, execute a `serialize()` function on the checkbox elements - the resulting string should be passed through `parse_str()` once it reaches the server.

Comment: the problem is i have another fields in the form and i need the array only from the ckeckboxes any help?